# Angular ResolveFn - inject() must be called from an injection context

Tags: angular, typescript, inject, angular-resolver

While attempting to deprecate instances of Angular's "Resolve" class implementation for the preferred functional implementation "ResolveFn", I ran into a perplexing issue.
I have a simple resolver that is preparing my data.
I am receiving this error but unclear on why:
"inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`."

**Code that Errors**

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, ResolveFn } from '@angular/router';
import { PrepareAdHocReportingService } from '@features/reporting/services/prepare-ad-hoc-reporting.service';
import { DashboardsService } from '../dashboards.service';

export const homeDashboardResolver: ResolveFn<void> = async (
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
) => {
    await inject(PrepareAdHocReportingService).resolve();
    const dashboardsService = inject(DashboardsService);
    await Promise.all([
      dashboardsService.fetchWidgets(),
      dashboardsService.getDashboardDetail(route.params.id)
    ]);
};
```

The most confusing part is that if I simply move the dashboardsService const up ONE line, it fixes the issue.

**Working Code**

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, ResolveFn } from '@angular/router';
import { PrepareAdHocReportingService } from '@features/reporting/services/prepare-ad-hoc-reporting.service';
import { DashboardsService } from '../dashboards.service';

export const homeDashboardResolver: ResolveFn<void> = async (
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
) => {
    const dashboardsService = inject(DashboardsService);
    await inject(PrepareAdHocReportingService).resolve();
    await Promise.all([
        dashboardsService.fetchWidgets(),
        dashboardsService.getDashboardDetail(route.params.id)
    ]);
};
```

Why does simply moving the const up solve this injection issue?

For additional context, both DashboardsService and PrepareAdHocReportingService are injected with "providedIn: 'root'".

`@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) export class PrepareAdHocReportingService {}`

`@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) export class DashboardsService {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awaiting a `Promise` does effectively exit the [injection context](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-context).

If you want to run in an injection context, you'll have to use [`runInInjectorContext`](https://angular.io/api/core/runInInjectionContext) after the await.

Comment: That makes sense - thank you!